# Hacked index.php file in website

Tags: php

I'm facing issue of **index.php** file hack every time. and i don't know what is the issue so can you please suggest me what is the issue in our website.

Developed website in :  **Core PHP with MySQL**

Comment: It is very unclear what you're asking here.

Comment: Someone has access to your server. You should wipe it / reinstall and make sure you install the latest versions of all software. And change your passwords.

Comment: And don't forget to check your PHP code carefully, it might be vulnerable to attacks.

Comment: Does someone else have your FTP password or your SSH key? I would try changing those first and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score -1):

Your description isn't too helpful but if I were you, I would download whole site to my local machine, scan it for viruses, delete everything from server, and re-upload everything back, update and change passwords for everything. Server, ftp, ssh, mysql...

Also you should probably check for MySQL injection CSRF or some other vulnerability as you have to pay attention to this since you haven't used any framework that could save you this kind of trouble to some extent